# I have no idea vs. I had no idea

Tags: meaning-in-context

When you are asked: How much do you think ''blue origin'' is spending at the moment to make space tourism possible?

And you responded:

> I **had** no idea vs. I **have** no idea

Do they have any differences?

Comment: One's the past tense and the other is the present tense. (And, for the most part, you should try to keep things in the same tense.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If asked a question to which you do not know the answer, you could say, 'I have no idea'. 'I have' is in the present tense, so you are saying in effect, 'I do not know at this present time'.

If someone makes a statement that surprises you (e.g. The US government is more than twenty-one trillion dollars in debt.), you could respond, 'I had no idea'. 'I had' is in the past tense, so you are saying in effect, 'I did not know that before now'.

Comment: In relation to this, can I say: ''You really **had** no idea how much work I **had** put in before I **got** to where I am now''--- are they parallel now?

Comment: They don't have to be parallel as there can be two time frames in this sentence. Now (for the hearers understanding) and past (when you did the work) so have then had is fine. If you have just told them how much work you have done then the Now shifts to the past (just before you told them) and had then had is appropriate as you have put.